# Wrong terms aggregate doc_count in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to find duplicates in the index by aggregating users by [array] + field using script.

My question is why does terms aggregate only counts **once** document by a given key (**smith@gmail.com_SMITH**). And is it possible to change this behavior.

Data:

```
POST users/user
{
    "name" :"SMITH",
    "emails" : [
       "smith@gmail.com"
    ]
}

POST users/user
{
    "name" :"SMITH",
    "emails" : [
      "mrsmith@gmail.com",
      "smith@gmail.com"
    ]
}
```

Distinct query:

```
POST users/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "duplicateCount": {
      "terms": {
        "script": {
          "inline": "doc['emails.keyword'].value + '_' + doc['name.keyword'].value"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

```
"aggregations": {
  "duplicateCount": {
    "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
    "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
    "buckets": [
      {
        "key": "mrsmith@gmail.com_SMITH",
        "doc_count": 1
      },
      {
        "key": "smith@gmail.com_SMITH",
        "doc_count": 1
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: This is because `doc['emails.keyword'].value` only takes the first value from your `emails` array. I'm not even sure you can use `values` instead as the script terms aggregation cannot return two terms.

Comment: @Val thanks for the hint. Guided me into the right direction.

Comment: Coo, but I'm not sure you're doing it correctly though ;-) You should simply have `keys.add(p);` in the for loop and nothing else

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be only to get the right terms aggregation count with `"terms"` + `"field"`.

If you try out this query, you can see the difference of `"terms"` + `"field"` and `"terms"` + `"script"`:

```
{
  "from" : 0,
  "size" : 0,
  "_source" : true,
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : [ {
        "match" : {
          "name" : {
            "query" : "SMITH",
            "operator" : "OR",
            "fuzziness" : "AUTO",
            "prefix_length" : 1,
            "max_expansions" : 50,
            "fuzzy_transpositions" : true,
            "lenient" : false,
            "zero_terms_query" : "NONE",
            "boost" : 1
          }
        }
      } ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "duplicateCount": {
      "terms": {
        "script": {
          "inline": "doc['emails.keyword'].value + '_' + doc['name.keyword'].value"
        }
      }
    },
    "duplicateCount2": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "emails.keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here are the results. See `duplicateCount2`:

```
{
  "took" : 53,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 3,
    "successful" : 3,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "duplicateCount2" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [ {
        "key" : "smith@gmail.com",
        "doc_count" : 2
      }, {
        "key" : "mrsmith@gmail.com",
        "doc_count" : 1
      } ]
    },
    "duplicateCount" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [ {
        "key" : "mrsmith@gmail.com_SMITH",
        "doc_count" : 1
      }, {
        "key" : "smith@gmail.com_SMITH",
        "doc_count" : 1
      } ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So I worked around it by iterating over terms array and manually creating desired keys:

```
def keys = []; 
for (p in doc['emails.keyword'].values) {
    keys.add(p + doc['name.keyword'].value);
} 
return keys;
```

Here's the result:

```
 "buckets": [
    {
      "key": "smith@gmail.com_SMITH",
      "doc_count": 2
    },
    {
      "key": "mrsmith@gmail.com_SMITH",
      "doc_count": 1
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Cool, `keys.add(p)` should be sufficient, though :-)